I was trying to create class mystack which would work like a stack datatype but i encountered unexpected output
This is the code where i tried to implement stack in c++ without pointer instead i used a interger variable called "top" to  hold the current position of stack and also i created constuctor to take in size of stack.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class mystack
{
    int top;
    int arr[5];
    int sizeofstack;

public:
    mystack(int j = 5)
    {
        arr[j];
        top = -1;
        // cout<<"constructor sizeofstack1:"<<sizeofstack<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofstack; i++)
        {
            cout << "sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 " << i << ":" << sizeofstack << endl;
            arr[i] = 0;
            cout << "sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 " << i << ":" << sizeofstack << endl;
        }
        sizeofstack = j;
        cout << "constructor sizeofstack2:" << sizeofstack << endl
             << "constructor j:" << j << endl;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == -1)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if (top == (sizeofstack - 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        cout << "The size of stack is " << sizeofstack << endl;
        return sizeofstack;
    }

    void push(int val)
    {
        cout << "value:" << top << endl
             << "sizeofstack:" << sizeofstack << endl;
        if (isFull())
        {
            cout << "stack overflow" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            top++;
            arr[top] = val;
        }
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "stack underflow" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[top] = 0;
            top--;
        }
    }

    int display()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "stack underflow" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = (sizeofstack - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            {

                cout << i << ":" << arr[i] << endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void pos(int i)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    mystack s1(9);
    s1.push(20);
    s1.display();
    return 0;
}

but when i tried to compile and run the program
The output was different from what i have expected
Output:
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 0:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 0:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 1:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 1:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 2:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 2:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 3:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 3:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 4:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 4:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 5:8
sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 5:0
constructor sizeofstack2:9
constructor j:9
value:-1
sizeofstack:9
8:0
7:7935504
6:0
5:9
4:0
3:0
2:0
1:0
0:20 

I assume that the issue lies in the constructor of the class.
The value of sizeofstack is changing to 0. I can't figure out why ?
mystack(int j = 5)
    {
        arr[j];
        top = -1;
        // cout<<"constructor sizeofstack1:"<<sizeofstack<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofstack; i++)
        {
            cout << "sizeofstack inside the constructor loop1 " << i << ":" << sizeofstack << endl;
            arr[i] = 0;
            cout << "sizeofstack inside the constructor loop2 " << i << ":" << sizeofstack << endl;
        }
        sizeofstack = j;
        cout << "constructor sizeofstack2:" << sizeofstack << endl
             << "constructor j:" << j << endl;
    }

I'm beginner in c++.  It would help me understand better.

What do you expect arr[j]; to do as the first statement in your constructor?  And you use sizeofstack before initializing/assigning it.

Two notes: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does; use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to. And isEmpty and isFull can be simply return top == -1; and return top == sizeofstack - 1; respectively.

You've defined arr to be an int[5] and arr[j]; accesses it out of bounds since j is 9. You probably want arr to be a std::vector<int> instead, then mystack(size_t j) : arr(j) {} would make it as large as you want.

"arr[j]" is used to assign to size of stack. im new to programming so

@DushyanthYadavv Re: "arr[j]" is used to assign to size of stack" - That's not how C++ works. You can't change the size of an array.  arr[j] is only accessing the already allocated memory. If you don't know the array size at compile time, you should use a std::vector<int> instead.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

@TedLyngmo but my intention is to create stack only using array in c++.

@DushyanthYadavv If you want to do it manually, you'll have to do what std::vector does internally and allocate the memory dynamically, using new[] and delete[] or using a smart pointer, like std::unique_ptr<int[]> / std::make_unique<int[]>(j). If you want fixed size stacks, you could also make a class template, taking the size as a template parameter.

@TedLyngmo but I wanted to know why the sizeofstack change to 0 when run it

@TedLyngmo Im learning data structure so I tried to create stack datatype. I didn't know what is dynamic memory allocation so I tried this way

Your current program has undefined behavior because you access arr out of bounds. The program could therefore do just about anything.  I think you'd be better off learning to use the existing class templates like std::vector and std::stack before trying to implement this yourself at this stage.

@TedLyngmo OK I get it thanks for your advice

You start with garbage in sizeofstack. You use it before initializing it to any particular value. In your example, it just so happens that the garbage value equals 8. Then, you assign zeros to arr[i]. Since arr is declared to have 5 elements, valid indexes are 0 through 4. When you get to arr[5] = 0, you scribble over the memory past the end of the array - and it just so happens that sizeofstack is located in memory immediately after arr, so arr[5] = 0 in effect does sizeofstack = 0.

@IgorTandetnik thank you!!! For clear the issue I had.
